# SessionStorage on a form with a default value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where it has a default value name "Alex". My goal is to save any changes made to the form through session Storage. It seems like my storage is getting saved on the browser, but my values are not updating in the form. On page refresh it keeps going back to the default value "Alex". I am not sure why that is happening if my values are being stored on the browser. Is my event handler the right approach for this?
JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2yL7k8w5/20/

```js
document.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  const save_name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  sessionStorage.getItem("name");
  sessionStorage.setItem("name", save_name);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="well">
  <form action="/person.php" method="post">
      <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input id = "name"class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" value="Alex">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach is okay but the problem is you've set value of input box in your HTML but you are not really updating the value with the value stored in sessionStorage.

So, use the following code to see the change:

```
let sname = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
let name = document.getElementById("name");
if(sname) {
    name.value = sname;
}
document.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  const save_name = name.value;
  console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("name"));
  sessionStorage.setItem("name", save_name);

});
```

Comment: This has been helpful and works as intended, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are saving in sessionStorage but you are not updating value on page load if session storage has any value in it.
Add below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
  if(name){
   document.getElementById("name").value = name
  }
})
```